# Counting frequency of runs of consecutive 1s in an array

Tags: scilab

I have defined an array of `arr=[0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1]`.

I would like to count the continuous repetition and store in another array.

For example above, the first repetition is 3 of 1s. So I assume the length of this continuous repetition is 3.

Therefore, the the array should be like arr[length]=1 . The 1 stands for it has been encountered once. The final output should be

arr[3]=2 //it means length of repetition with 3 of 1s has been encountered twice

arr[2]=1 //length of repetition with 2 has been encountered once.

Below is my code progress so far.

```
err=0;
no_err=0;
flag=0;

arr=[0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1] //assume 15
for x=1:15;
val=arr(x);//access array values
if(val==0)//if no error
flag=0; //indicates no error
elseif(val==1) //if there is an error
flag=1; //indicates error
end
if(flag==0)
no_err=no_err+1;//counter of no error
err=0; //reset error to zero
elseif(flag==1)//
err=err+1;//
tmperr=err;//will keep updating with latest err count length
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the logic is reasonable, but this part is strange:

```
if(flag==0)
 ....
elseif(flag==1)
```

This could be simply `else`. More importantly, the state of flag could have been changed by the earlier part of the loop, which will render the logic of the second if statement invalid.

I suggest considering four scenarios, focusing on counting only repetitions of 1s:

- flag is 0 and value is 0: do nothing (no need to have a clause for this)
- flag is 1 and value is 1: increment the count of consecutive 1s
- flag is 0 and value is 1: set the flag to 1, set the count of consecutive 1s to 1.
- flag is 1 and value is 0: set the flag to 0, record the count of 1s in the output array.

Since the second bullet item does not change the state of flag, it can be dealt with first; the two others are considered within if/elseif construction.

Also, the end of array should be ending the current run of 1s. Instead of writing a separate clause for this, it's easier to pad the given array with 0.

```
err=0
flag=0

arr=[0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1]
output = zeros(arr)
paddedarr = [arr 0] 
for x=1:length(paddedarr)
    val=paddedarr(x) 
    if (val==1 & flag==1)
      err=err+1
    end
    if (val==1 & flag==0) 
      flag = 1
      err = 1
    elseif (val==0 & flag==1) 
      output(err) = output(err)+1
      flag = 0
      err = 0
  end
end
```

Output:

```
0.    1.    2.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.
```

Note that I used `length` command instead of assuming the length of array.